# BigQuery: Sample a varying number of rows per group

Tags: random, google-bigquery

I have two tables. One has a list of `item`s, and for each item, a number `n`.

```
item | n
--------
a    | 1
b    | 2
c    | 3
```

The second one has a list of rows containing `item`, `uid`, and other rows.

```
item | uid | data
------------------
a    | x   | foo
a    | x   | baz
a    | x   | bar
a    | z   | arm
a    | z   | leg
b    | x   | eye
b    | x   | eye
b    | x   | eye
b    | x   | eye
b    | z   | tap
c    | y   | tip
c    | z   | top
```

I would like to sample, for each `(item,uid)` pair, `n` rows (arbitrary, it's better if this is uniformly random, but it doesn't have to be). In the example above, I want to keep maximum one row per user for item `a`, two rows per user for item `b`, and three rows per user to item `c`:

```
item | uid | data
------------------
a    | x   | baz
a    | z   | arm
b    | x   | eye
b    | x   | eye
b    | z   | tap
c    | y   | tip
c    | z   | top
```

`ARRAY_AGG` with `LIMIT n` doesn't work for two reasons: first, I suspect that given that `n` can be large (on the order of 100,000), this won't scale. The second, more fundamental problem is that `n` [needs to be a constant](http://cloud/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg).

[Table sampling](http://cloud/bigquery/docs/table-sampling) also doesn't seem to solve my problem, since it's per-table, and also only supports sampling a fixed percentage of rows, rather than a fixed *number* of rows.

Are there any other options?

Comment: maybe [table-sampling](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-sampling) could be useful

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I edited the question to explain why I don't think that'll be enough to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below solution

```
select * except(n)
from rows_list
join items_list 
using(item)
where true
qualify row_number() over win <= n
window win as (partition by item, uid order by rand())
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]